# Combinator /: in scala

Tags: scala

What is the meaning of this combinator in scala? `/:`

I've found it in several examples:

```
override def toString(): String = {
    ("" /: cfg) ((str: String, b: BasicBlock) => str + "Block " + b.id)
  }
```

or

```
val successorIns = b.getSuccessors().map(in(_))
val newValue = (top() /: successorIns) (meet(_, _))
```

Comment: It would help if you could say which part exactly of the documentation you didn't understand, so that the Scala developers can improve the documentation for future readers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is shorthand for `foldLeft`. You can see the definition of it [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html).